# Angular Material table datasource is not syncing with my HTTP calls and not re rendering the dom

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

So I'll get straight to the point, im building an angular application and I am using Angular Material Tables. Bit of a disclaimer I'm pretty new to Angular and development

So basically I'm creating a dataSource variable to where I'm going to constantly update my tables data with each call and this is the code where that happens

`const siteFilter: SiteFilter = {}; this.siteControllerService.getAllSitesFilteredAndSorted(siteFilter, this.page).subscribe((data) => { this.data = data; // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion this.data.sort((a, b) => (a.siteId! > b.siteId! ? 1 : -1)); this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data); this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; });`

(Originally the last 3 lines were also in ngoninit and I put them into a 1 second timeout which did solve my issue but it is extremely not good at all, I'm also aware that its bad practice to put this into my constructor but its there because I am in the belief that if it runs before my oninit and I get the data and then trigger a detechchanges on my oninit it should detect that my data is not up to date with the current dom and re render it.)

my @Component looks like this:

`@Component({ changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, selector: 'app-table', templateUrl: './table.component.html', styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'], })`

And inside the ngOnInit I am calling the this.ref.detectChanges(); which is in the constructor as this:
`private ref: ChangeDetectorRef`

Now the reason this is all here is that right now the above HTTP call returns me an array of objects I put that object into the dataSource and my table should re render with the newly added data as far as I'm aware, but it came to my attention that sometimes I make a call to get 20 entries of the data I want, and only 14 or 16 or however much is visible on my table and so I got confused logged the response and even though my table had 16 entries the object I got was precisely 20 as much as I asked for.

Not sure how this stackoverflow works but I'll continue on inside the what did I try section so I tried to use a changeDetector since I realsed that the data is there inside my variable but its not updatin the DOM I implemented the above example and I'm still on the same issue, as if the http response time is a big longer than usual then the data I see in my table is not what the dataSource is at that moment.

Which means basically that the dom is not representing the actual data inside my dataSource.

So my question is basically is there a way for me to detect whenever my http call a 100% ended and then I do the this.dataSource = new MatTable... etc. I've tried going into the success arrow function inside the call but that didin't do much either and I've also looked up how async await works but I got really nowhere there since im really  newbie at this still and have no idea how to implement an async await functionality.

Not sure if this information is relevant at all but I'll share this since If it is then thank god we got this out of the way but none of the http calls are created by me or anyone else at that matter, this generated through the dto-s the BE has and whatnot which is is somehow compiled automatically into a service and downloaded as an NPM package from an artifactory and we use the Service which this package has and we cannot edit the http calls at all we just use the respective method and give the asked data to them. Not sure if this is relevant or a good to know for the question but here it is.

If I could get any direction to go to and help that would be great.

(I asked chat GPT also if someone suggest me that, offered me the above example which didn't work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after 2 weeks of struggling to understand why this would hapen I have finally been able to figure out a solution if anyone is ever interested or has a similar issue this is what solved it for me.

I've moved the logic to get the data from the API to its own method as shown here:

```
     GetAllSites() {
        const siteFilter: SiteFilter = {};
        this.siteControllerService
          .getAllSitesFilteredAndSorted(siteFilter, this.page)
          .pipe(first())
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.data = data;
            this.data.sort((a, b) => (a.siteId! > b.siteId! ? 1 : -1));
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
            this.ref.detectChanges();
          });
```

And now this is the first thing what is called inside my ngOnInit hook.

The only difference is that im using a .pipe(first()) before my subscription, I have played around with this solution with different sizes of data and simulation of backend delay and this seems to be working, and whenever the call is finished the dataSource is updated correctly and the dom is refreshing with the newly updated data.

What a ride.